# Import a std::vector<Mat> to specific index of 3D cv::Mat

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have a vectorimageSlices and a 3D :

```
cv::Mat RTstruct3D(3,DImensions3D, CV_8U, Scalar(0))
```

I want to put my vector into the specific index of 3D cv::Mat.

```
        //Make a 3D Organ
        int programCounter = 0;
        vector<Mat>imageSlices;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < Npoint_Z.size(); k++)
        {
            Mat finalSliceImage = Mat :: zeros(DImensions3D[0], DImensions3D[1],CV_8U);
            vector<vector<int>> polies;
            for (size_t h = 0; h < Npoint_Z[k][0]; h++)
            {
                vector<int>x_y;
                x_y.push_back(ContourData[programCounter][0]); //x
                x_y.push_back(ContourData[programCounter][1]); //y
                polies.push_back(x_y);
                programCounter++;
            }
            fillPoly(finalSliceImage, polies, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            imageSlices.push_back(finalSliceImage);
        }
        //Add Organ to RTSTRUCT 3D
        Mat RTstruct3D(3,DImensions3D, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
```

Something like this image:
[image]

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging channels in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582082/merging-channels-in-opencv)

Comment: @beaker No, I don't want to merge them. I just want to put them in a specific index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
        //Add Organ to RTSTRUCT 3D
        vector<Mat>RTstruct3D(DImensions3D[0], Mat(DImensions3D[1], DImensions3D[2], CV_8U));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Npoint_Z.size(); i++)
        {
            RTstruct3D[Npoint_Z[i][1]] = imageSlices[i];
        }
```

Comment: First time seeing `f` as loop index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 
[Mat cv::Mat::operator() (   const std::vector< Range > &    ranges  )   const](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa9bf4fcbb6e854a6db7b7254a205fac9)
 to access the submatrix and then use 
[Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (   const Mat &     m   )](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302)

Example:

```
int main() {
    cv::Mat m1(10, 10, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(1));
    vector<cv::Mat> v = {m1, m1, m1};
    std::array<int, 3> dims = {10, 10, 10};
    cv::Mat m2(3, dims.data(), CV_8U);
    vector<cv::Range> rV = {cv::Range(0, 1), cv::Range(0, 10), cv::Range(0, 10)};
    m2(rV.data()) = v[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain more about your code.